#  STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION on new c++ eclipse project

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I'm newbie on C++, and I had download Eclipse for C++ development, I had download MinGW too because I want to develope cocos2d-x apps.

My problem is that when I try to create a new C++ project I get a window from Windows that says seq.exe stop working, and seq.exe.stackdump file is created with this inside:

> MSYS-1.0.17 Build:2011-04-24 23:39 Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>   at eip=00000000        eax=6855477C ebx=6855022C ecx=0001B008
>   edx=00000080 esi=00000000 edi=685500D4 ebp=0028FEC8 esp=0028FEAC
>   program=d:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\seq.exe cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053
>   gs=002B ss=002B Stack trace: Frame     Function  Args End of stack
>   trace

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance. 
Javier.-

Comment: Are you sure that u have sufficient access privileges for seq.exe , i.e. Admin rights

Comment: I think I have all access privileges, but now I realized that I was selecting the wrong project type. I was selecting GNU Autotool, now I select Executable, and it works perfect. Thank you.